# can i execute a definition written in ruby watir in an excel sheet?

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a definition which looks like this,

```
 def Execute_Statement(obj_type,obj_name,obj_value,name)
  sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
  sheet1.each do |row|
  break if row[0].nil?
  if (obj_type == "Edit")
  @browser.text_field(:obj_name => row[0]).when_present.set(name)
  end
 end 
end
```

In my excel i have 5 columns which looks like this, Execute_Statement "Edit" "id" "UserName" "name",

I want to know if it is possible to call the methods written in ruby by an excel

Comment: You could write a Ruby script that reads in the Excel spreadsheet and passes the columns as parameters to your `Execute_Statement` method. Btw, method names should (almost) always be lowercase.

Comment: Can you help me with the ruby code.

Comment: Sorry I am not going to write the code for you. Try to start something, if you get stuck come back and ask a question about it. It is much easier to help someone when there's actual code that we can talk about and improve. For reading Excel files you can try [the Spreadsheet gem](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html). The rest is pretty straight forward.

Comment: i think the code i have posted in the question is supposed to read the excel. i have declared the excel outside the method.

Comment: I see. Can you post the whole code, or at least everything relevant? See http://sscce.org/ for how to ask a good question on your code. What you post should be executable, but not include any unnecessary clutter so others can dive in and try to fix the errors. If it's just incomplete snippets nobody feels like inventing bits and pieces around that code and eventually you will only get a few vague and untested answers.

Comment: require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'spreadsheet'
require 'watir-webdriver'
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
book = Spreadsheet.open 'path to the excel'

browser = Watir::Browser.start("URL")                               def execute_statement(obj_type,obj_name,obj_value,name)
    sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
     sheet1.each do |row|
     break if row[0].nil?
     if (obj_type == "Edit")
     @browser.text_field(:obj_name =row[0]).when_present.set(name)
    end
  end 
end

Comment: Ok whatever, check out my answer.

Comment: @p11y Your patience is admirable.;) Nandish Shetty, you can't post code in the comments like that. As you can see it is a horrible mess, and cannot be formatted. Next time, please just edit your question and paste it there instead.

Comment: i wasnt aware i could do tat, so jus added it in the comments. Next time i will make sure this is not repeated

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'spreadsheet'

def execute_statement(obj_type, obj_name, obj_value, name)
  # do something
end

book = Spreadsheet.open '/path/to/an/excel-file.xls'
sheet = book.worksheet(0)

sheet.each do |row|
  execute_statement(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
end
```